# Не публикуется добавленная библиотека на сервер

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть такая ситуация:
Я в свой **ASP.NET MVC** проект добавил некую библиотеку. При запуске на локальной машине, все работает хорошо. Как только я запаблишил приложение на сервер, функционал, который использует новую библиотеку, не работает. Я обнаружил что  папке /bin просто нет данной библиотеки. Я решил перенести "вручную" и все заработало.

**ВОПРОС:** *Почему данная библиотека не перенеслась на сервер?*

P.S. Библиотеку добавлял так:

1. Получил по скайпу dll.
2. Перенес его в папку bin моего проекта.
3. Нажал кнопку AddReference -> Browse и указал путь к dll которая
   лежит в bin.

Comment: А почему она должна была перенестись? В свойствах ссылки на либу вы выставляли опцию копировать в local dir? https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD8Uc.png

Comment: Проверьте copy local в свойствах референса на библиотеку. Если уже стоит true - поменяйте на false, и обратно на true, чтобы значение было выделено болдом